# Image Resize Aliasing in WPF v4 but not under v3.5

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, antialiasing, dithering

I am using WPF for an image resizing pipeline which has been working beautifully under .NET v3.5. I just upgraded the project to target v4.0 and now all of my resized images are heavily aliased. None of the image pipeline code has changed.

1. Has a default WPF setting changed between v3.5 and v4.0?
2. How do I control the dithering of my resized bitmap images in WPF?

I'm using `BitmapImage`, `DrawingVisual`, `DrawingContext`, `RenderTargetBitmap`, `BitmapEncoder`, and `BitmapFrame` but I'm not seeing any properties related to dithering. GDI+ had a bunch of settings, so I'm guessing that I'm missing something.

**Update:** it appears that all of the solutions I've seen assume a Window object or XAML environment. This runs inside a Windows Service which has no UI. I need a way to programmatically affect this setting.

I specifically switched from GDI+ to WPF because GDI+ has memory leaks in long running processes like services & web apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've been able to affect the setting of `BitmapScalingMode` is to inherit from the `DrawingVisual` class and set it via its protected accessor:

```
// exposes BitmapScalingMode (also works for other protected properties)
public class MyDrawingVisual : DrawingVisual
{
    public BitmapScalingMode BitmapScalingMode
    {
        get { return this.VisualBitmapScalingMode; }
        set { this.VisualBitmapScalingMode = value; }
    }
}
```

If anyone else knows of a better way to set this, I would be excited to hear about it.

It seems that this would work:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(myDrawingVisual, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
```

...but it does not. Apparently being outside of the XAML windowing runtime must mean that it cannot set the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

The default BitmapScalingMode was Fant in 3.0 but in 4.0 it is now BiLinear.  You can change the default a few different ways.  A couple [described here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522439/allow-setting-the-default-renderoptions-bitmapscalingmode?wa=wsignin1.0).

Comment: The link is not quite the context that I'm using it. I am using the classes and calling them programmatically rather than declaratively. I've tried both calling `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(..., BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality)` and `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(..., BitmapScalingMode.Fant)` on all of those objects above which implement `DependencyObject`. Doesn't appear to have any effect. The docs imply that the object should be a  descendant of `UIElement` or `DrawingGroup`. I use neither.